# Losslessly upsize PDF canvas to A4 without resizing/modifying the content

Tags: pdf

I want to losslessly upsize the canvas of a PDF to A4 without resizing/modifying the content.

Here's the document I have :

```bash
$ pdfinfo myFile.pdf 
Creator:        EO.Pdf
Producer:       EO.Pdf 16.2.50.0
CreationDate:   Mon Jun 17 14:30:34 2019
ModDate:        Mon Jun 17 14:30:34 2019
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          10
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 774 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      656721 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
$ identify myFile.pdf
myFile.pdf[0] PDF 595x774 595x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.030u 0:00.029
myFile.pdf[1] PDF 595x774 595x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.020u 0:00.029
myFile.pdf[2] PDF 595x774 595x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.020u 0:00.019
myFile.pdf[3] PDF 595x774 595x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.020u 0:00.019
myFile.pdf[4] PDF 595x774 595x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.010u 0:00.019
myFile.pdf[5] PDF 595x774 595x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.010u 0:00.019
myFile.pdf[6] PDF 595x774 595x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.010u 0:00.009
myFile.pdf[7] PDF 595x774 595x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.010u 0:00.009
myFile.pdf[8] PDF 595x774 595x774+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.000u 0:00.009
myFile.pdf[9] PDF 567x737 567x737+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 58.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I tried this, the target size is fine but I got significant quality loss :

```bash
$ convert myFile.pdf -page A4 myFile_A4.pdf
$ pdfinfo myFile_A4.pdf | egrep "Page( size|s):"
Pages:          10
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
```

How can I resize the canvas up to 595 x 842 pts without modifying the content of the PDF file, using an open source or free app ?

Comment: Does it have to be imagemagick or are other tools allowed too?

Comment: @Freddy No, any other free/opensource tool is just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the paper size with `pdftocairo`:

```
pdftocairo -pdf -paper A4 myFile.pdf myFile_A4.pdf
# or
pdftocairo -pdf -paperw 595 -paperh 842 myFile.pdf myFile_A4.pdf
```

To change the paper size and scale its content (what you probably don't want):

```
pdftocairo -pdf -paper A4 -expand myFile.pdf myFile_A4.pdf
```

Comment: thanks a lot man :)